# Bringing the bench press together

Tags: bench-press

I got all the cues for bench press that is needed I think:

1. Arching the back
2. Engaging the lats  by tuckign the shoulder
3. Planting feet
4. Valsalva maneveur

The only problem I have is in bringing all of these together. I seem to be able two and at good days three together, but it seems for me to bring all of them together. Especially those in the first three, because it seems to me that focusing one of them kilsl my ability to focus on the others.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep practicing. Eventually it's becomes a natural part of the way you bench and you don't even have to think about it. Muscle memory will kick in and you'll get straight in to position without too much thought.

To make it easier you can practice the two most important things, arched back and tucking your shoulders. Then practice practice practice. Once you have enough brain power to add the third thing, practice that. Then practice the fourth.

The fifth thing you forgot to mention was leg drive. Basically push your feet away from you. Once you've got the feet planting part down, practice the leg drive.

Comment: Another important thing I'd mention is just listen to your body and to what feels right.  In the beginning I never had a gym coach and I never watched tutorials on how to do exercises. I just figured it out for myself. I started to arch my back because it just felt right and made the lift easier. It wasn't until a few months after that I watched some videos on bench pressing that I discovered arching was an essential part of proper form.